# Java: springrframework.beans not accessible even though module-info opens the necessary package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, module-info

I have a package `warehouse.controller` where I am trying to `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;`, but I am getting an error:
`The import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired cannot be resolvedJava`

So far my `module-info.java` looks like this:

```
module warehouse {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.base;
    requires java.sql;

    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires java.transaction;

    opens warehouse.controller to javafx.fxml, spring.beans, spring.context;
    opens warehouse;

    exports warehouse;
    exports warehouse.controller;
}
```

And my `pom.xml` consist of these dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I would gladly appreciate any suggestions on how can I resolve the described error.

Comment: Try maven clean and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Hi You're missing out of spring boot starter web in your pom.xml, add the below dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly adding this dependency to `pom.xml` and `requires spring.boot.starter;` to my `module-info.java` did not solve the issue.